# How can I list the messages in my mailbox?

Tags: mail-command

Using the `mail` command it shows the messages I have and drops me into a prompt, but I cannot figure how to list the messages. Here is the help screen for mail:

```
Mail Command                    Description
-------------------------       ---------------------------------------------
t [message list]                type messages(s).
more [message list]             read message(s), through the $PAGER
n                               goto and type next message.
e [message list]                edit message(s)
f [message list]                give head lines of messages.
d [message list]                delete message(s).
s [message list] <file>         append message(s) to file.
u [message list]                undelete message(s).
R [message list]                reply to message sender(s).
r [message list]                reply to message sender(s) and all recipients.
p [message list]                print message list.
pre [message list]              make messages go back to /var/mail.
m <recipient list>              mail to specific recipient(s).
q                               quit, saving unresolved messages in mbox.
x                               quit, do not remove system mailbox.
h                               print out active message headers.
!                               shell escape.
| [msglist] command             pipe message(s) to shell command.
pi [msglist] command            pipe message(s) to shell command.
cd [directory]                  chdir to directory or home if none given
fi <file>                       switch to file (%=system inbox, %user=user's
```

As you can see, none of these commands list the messages in the mailbox.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## h

Although the help text may not be particularly clear, `h` is the command to list messages.  Placing a valid message number after `h` will list a range of messages containing the given one.  For instance, if you have 50 messages and type `h30`, it may list messages 21 through 40.

## f

For displaying only particular messages, you can use `f` with various qualifiers.  So, `f*` displays everything, while `f 1-10 20-24` displays the messages 1 through 10 and 20 through 24.

Comment: +1, h1,h100,h200 so on

Comment: works on my version.